Datadog - How do I configure a monitor to send out alerts regardless of resolved status
I have a monitor that sends an alert every 30 minutes. The issue is that after it sends out a list of log messages with errors, the monitor moves into an errored state until there's a 30 period time interval with no errors.
Is it possible to update the monitor to send out error messages from the time period regardless of the resolved status and such?
I'm creating my monitor with terraform, the code is attached below:
resource "datadog_monitor" "this" {
  enable_logs_sample       = true
  evaluation_delay         = 0
  groupby_simple_monitor   = false
  message                  = <<-EOT
          {{#is_alert}}
          ${local.dd_formatted_slack_channel}
          {{/is_alert}}

          {{#is_recovery}}
          Skip recovery alerts
          {{/is_recovery}}
        EOT
  name                     = var.monitor_name
  notification_preset_name = "hide_all"
  on_missing_data          = "default"
  new_group_delay          = 0
  notify_audit             = false
  notify_by                = []
  priority                 = var.priority
  require_full_window      = false

  tags      = [for k, v in var.tags : "${k}:${v}"]
  timeout_h = 0
  type      = "log alert"

  query = "formula(\"${local.service_keys}\").last(\"${var.alert_window}\") > 0"

  variables {
    dynamic "event_query" {
      for_each = local.service_map
      iterator = event_query
      content {
        data_source = "logs"
        indexes     = ["*"]
        name        = event_query.key
        compute {
          aggregation = "count"
          interval    = 0
        }
        search {
          query = "kube_cluster_name:${var.cluster_name} service:${event_query.value} env:${var.environment} status:error"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  monitor_thresholds {
    critical = "0"
  }

}

